# Retain media fragment music playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-dialogfragment

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` I use to play recordings. But the fragment is being recreated from scratch and destroying on configuration change.

I've trying to find a lifecycle event only called when the fragment is completely destroyed. But all of `onDetach()` `onDestroy()` `onDestroyView()` are being called on any configuration change (e.g rotation change).

I've tried `retainInstance` but `onDestroy()` is still being called.

I've seen other players do it like Google Play Music with the small dialog. Is it because they're using an Activity instead of a fragment? Something more independent probably has more power, but it's still a full activity, harder to control.

Comment: Might [`setRetainInstance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#setretaininstance) help here?

Comment: Tried it, didn't help. `onDestroy()` is still being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was from the libraries, the dialog was being dismissed even tho the fragment isn't destroyed.

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    if (dialog != null && retainInstance) {
        dialog.setDismissMessage(null)
    }
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

This code fixed it, now the fragment is retained and `onDestroy()` isn't being called anymore.